# node-sass error when building in Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, node-sass

I have a problem with building a node project, specifically when compiling sass within a `node:8.11.4` Docker container. I receive the following error:

```
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@8.11.4 | linux | x64
.
.
.
In file included from ../src/binding.cpp:3:0:
../src/sass_context_wrapper.h:8:26: fatal error: sass/context.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sass/context.h>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
```

It appears as though the error is caused by:

```
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/linux-x64-57_binding.node"
```

I know this isn't proxy related, I've tried downloading the file directly and I also receive a 404. I've made sure to remove my `package-lock.json` file prior to building, just in case it was a problem with a cross-platform version of node-sass.

Is there something I can do to remedy this?

Comment: `https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/linux-x64-57_binding.node` is a 404 to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no download for x64-57 on v3.13.1, as v3.13.1 doesn't support node 8.

https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v3.13.1

https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1932

So you can either update node-sass 4.5+ or downgrade node.js below 8

Comment: Yes, I kind of gathered that. I'm not sure how to remedy this. Is it a build configuration that needs to change such that it tries to download another version?

Comment: You either need to lower your node version or update node-sass to a later release

Comment: Thanks. Is there a compatibility matrix? Otherwise, I'll have to  just keep guessing the node/sass versions until I get it right.

Comment: upgrade to node sass 4.5+ per https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1932

Comment: `"node-sass": "^4.9.3"`
`node@8.11.4`
`npm@5.6.0`

Comment: O_o that's what your package.json is?... and it's trying to download v3.13.1? It's likely a dependency of another package then?

Comment: OH DAMMIT!! Sorry, I was looking at the wrong branch of our project. Indeed the branch I'm building off of is `^v3.10.0` of `node-sass`.